# selecting textViews and getting their values

Tags: java, android

I am trying to accomplish following things

Suppose I have 5-6 `TextViews` with values  `S N A K E`

Now, I want to press `S` textView then slide my finger over `N` to select it too and then move my way to E. I want to do that so that i can get "`SNAKE`" in my string or char sequence etc

If there is any idea do share me. I can't get it how to use `onTouch` here.
Also, i am adding `textViews` dynamically so i am setting their ids dynamically too
Best Regards

Comment: use someting like textview.setOntouchListener()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never done this, but here's a thought.

Assuming all your textviews are in some sort of layout, you could disable the focusability on your textview and create an onTouch listener on your underlying container.

*Start tracking on Mouse Down events*

```
@Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) { 
    if(event.getAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
         captureInput = true;
    }
}
```

*On your ACTION_MOVE event, check if the current position is above a textview, if so, capture that value*

```
@Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) { 
    int action = event.getAction();

    if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
         captureInput = true;
    }
    else if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE
    {
        //get x/y of your finger
         int X = (int)event.getX();   
         int Y = (int)event.getY();

        //Somehow check if the x,y are overlapping with one of your textivews
        // If so, add that textview's text to your list
        // Below is pseudo code
        /* for(TextView curTV: allTextViews)
           {
               if(isOverlapping(X,Y))
               {
                   listOfSwipedCharacters.add(curTV.getText());
               }
           }
     }


}
```

*Lastly, when the user releases their finger, stop tracking and do something with the word list*

```
@Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) { 
    int action = event.getAction();

    if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
         captureInput = true;
    }
    else if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE
    {
        //get x/y of your finger
         int X = (int)event.getX();   
         int Y = (int)event.getY();

        //Somehow check which textview the X,Y coords are overlapping
        // Below is pseudo code
        /* for(TextView curTV: allTextViews)
           {
               if(isOverlapping(X,Y))
               {
                   listOfSwipedCharacters += (curTV.getText());
               }
           }*/
     }
     else if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
     {
         captureInput = false;
         //Do whatever you want with the string of information that you've captured
     }
```

}

Once again, I have no idea if that will work, it's just a guess at an approach. I suspect performance of cycling through each textview to check for overlaps will be pretty crappy, so there may be a more efficient approach than running a for loop.

Since you know you can't jump over letters when swyping, you could create a short list of all the possible swipe locations (surrounding letters) whenever you add a new letter. Then on your mouse event, check if any of those letters have been hit by the mouse move event. For example, in a standard word search game, once you select a letter, there are only 9 other possible locations for you to swipe (the surrounding letters), so you should only bother checking if those 9 locations have been hit when you capture the mouse move event.

Edit: I suppose you could use the solution above if you attached an onTouch listener to *each* and every textview. The same premise in regards to touch would apply: Down = start capture, move = capture text, up = stop capture. It would save you from having to identify which textview is being hovered as the textview that fires the onTouch event will be the one that the user is swiping across.